# C# and ANTLR4: Handling "include" directives when parsing a file

Tags: c#, parsing, include, antlr4, antlr4cs

I’m in a situation that, using ANTLR, I’m trying to parse input files that contains references to other files inside them, just like `#include "[insert file name]"` of C language.

One suggested approach is:

1. Parse the root file, saving said references as nodes (so, specific Grammar rules)
2. Visit the tree searching for "reference" nodes
3. for each reference node, parse the file referenced and substitute the node with the newly generated tree
4. repeat this process recursively, to handle multiple levels of inclusions

The problem with this solution is that the referenced files might be completely partial (see includes inside the body of a C function). In order to parse such files, I would have to implement a different parser to handle the fragmented grammar.

Is there any valid/suggested approach to (literally) inject the new file inside the ongoing parsing process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem can be achieved by overriding Scanner's behavior and specifically, the `NextToken()` method.
This is necassary since the EOF token cannot be handled by the ANTLR lexer grammar ( to my best knowledge ) and any actions
attached to the lexer rule recognizing the EOF are simply ignored (as shown in the code bellow). Thus, it is necessary to
implement this behaviour directly into the scanner method.

So assume we have a parser grammar

```
parser grammar INCParserGrammar;

@parser::members {
        public static Stack<ICharStream> m_nestedfiles = new Stack<ICharStream>();
}

options { tokenVocab = INCLexerGrammar; }

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

compileUnit
    :   (include_directives | ANY )+ ENDOFFILE
    ;

include_directives : INCLUDEPREFIX FILE DQUOTE
                     ;
```

A `static public Stack<ICharStream>` (i.e. `mySpecialFileStack`) should be introduced inside grammar's members. This stack will be used to store the Character Steams associated with the files that take part in the parsing. The Character Streams are push to
this stack as new files are encountered with the include statements

and a lexer grammar

```
   lexer grammar INCLexerGrammar;

   @lexer::header {
    using System;
    using System.IO;
   }

   @lexer::members { 
    string file;
    ICharStream current;
    
   }


/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
INCLUDEPREFIX : '#include'[ \t]+'"' {                                                 
                                      Mode(INCLexerGrammar.FILEMODE);
                                    };

// The following ruls has always less length matched string that the the rule above
ANY : ~[#]+ ;


ENDOFFILE : EOF { // Any actions in the this rule are ignored by the ANTLR lexer };


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

mode FILEMODE;
FILE : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'.'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ {  file= Text;
                                                StreamReader s = new StreamReader(file);
                                                INCParserGrammar.m_nestedfiles.Push(_input);                                                
                                                current =new AntlrInputStream(s);           
                                            
                                             };
DQUOTE: '"'  {  
                this._input = current;
                Mode(INCLexerGrammar.DefaultMode);  };
```

The overriden body of NextToken() method will be placed in the .g4.cs file which purpose is to extend
the generated scanner class given that the generated scanner class is decorated with the "partial" keyword

After the partial Scanner Class associated to the given grammar is generated navigate to the source code of the
ANTLR4 Lexer Class as given in the ANTLR Runtime and Copy ALL the original code to this new method  and,
in the middle do-while block (right after the try-catch block) add the following code:

```
if (this._input.La(1) == -1)
{
    if ( mySpecialFileStack.Count == 0 )
        this._hitEOF = true;
    else
        this._input = mySpecialFileStack.Pop();
}
```

The full body of the NextToken() method override is

```
public override IToken NextToken() {
            int marker = this._input != null ? this._input.Mark() : throw new InvalidOperationException("nextToken requires a non-null input stream.");
            label_3:
            try {
                while (!this._hitEOF) {
                    this._token = (IToken)null;
                    this._channel = 0;
                    this._tokenStartCharIndex = this._input.Index;
                    this._tokenStartCharPositionInLine = this.Interpreter.Column;
                    this._tokenStartLine = this.Interpreter.Line;
                    this._text = (string)null;
                    do {
                        this._type = 0;
                        int num;
                        try {
                            num = this.Interpreter.Match(this._input, this._mode);
                        } catch (LexerNoViableAltException ex) {
                            this.NotifyListeners(ex);
                            this.Recover(ex);
                            num = -3;
                        }

                        if (this._input.La(1) == -1) {
                            if (INCParserGrammar.m_nestedfiles.Count == 0 ) {
                                this._hitEOF = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this._input = INCParserGrammar.m_nestedfiles.Pop();
                            }
                        }

                        if (this._type == 0)
                            this._type = num;
                        if (this._type == -3)
                            goto label_3;
                    }
                    while (this._type == -2);
                    if (this._token == null)
                        this.Emit();
                    return this._token;
                }
                this.EmitEOF();
                return this._token;
            } finally {
                this._input.Release(marker);
            }
        }
```

Now, when you recognize a file inside your code that should be parsed, simply add the following action

```
FILE
    : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'.'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ {
        StreamReader s = new StreamReader(Text);
        mySpecialFileStack.Push(_input);                                                
        _input = new AntlrInputStream(s);                                               
    };
    
DQUOTE: '"'  {  this._input = current;
            Mode(INCLexerGrammar.DefaultMode);  };
//***Warning:***
// Be careful when your file inclusion is enclosed inside quotes or other symbols, or if  
// the filename-to-be-included is not the last token that defines an inclusion: `_input`  
// should only be switched AFTER the inclusion detection is completely found (i.e. after  
// the closing quote has been recognized).
```

Finally the main program is given below where it is apparent that the root file is added first in the ICharStream stack

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
            var a = new StreamReader("./root.txt");
            var antlrInput = new AntlrInputStream(a);
            INCParserGrammar.m_nestedfiles.Push(antlrInput);
            var lexer = new INCLexerGrammar(antlrInput);
            var tokens = new BufferedTokenStream(lexer);
            var parser = new INCParserGrammar(tokens);
            parser.compileUnit();
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading Mr. Grigoris's answer helped me to discover another possible solution for my problem:

While trying to figure out how does the suggested solution work, I stumbled upon `public virtual IToken EmitEOF()` method. If the code that Mr. Grigoris provided gets placed inside this function (with minor changes), everything seems to work as intended.

That gave me the opportunity to *override the functionality* of `EmitEOF()` directly from `@members` block of lexer, without having to create a whole new file or to understand how my current parser's `NextToken()` method works.

**Lexer Grammar:**

```
lexer grammar INCLexerGrammar;  
  
@lexer::header {  
    using System;  
    using System.IO;  
    using System.Collections.Generic;  
}  
  
@lexer::members {   
  
    private Stack<ICharStream> _nestedFiles = new Stack<ICharStream>();  
      
    public override IToken EmitEOF(){  
        if (_nestedFiles.Count == 0 ) {  
            return base.EmitEOF();  
        };  
        this._hitEOF = false;  
        this._input = _nestedFiles.Pop();  
        return this.NextToken();  
    }  
}  
  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
// Default Mode /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
  
// Skipped because we don't want to hide INCLUDEPREFIX's existance from parser  
INCLUDEPREFIX : '#include'[ \t]+'"' { Mode(INCLexerGrammar.FILEMODE); } -> skip;  

// This is the only valid token our Grammar accepts
ANY : ~[#]+ ;  
  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
mode FILEMODE; //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
  
// Skipped because we don't want to hide FILE's existance from parser  
FILE : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'.'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ {   
  
    // Create new StreamReader from the file mentioned  
    StreamReader s = new StreamReader(Text);  
      
    // Push the old stream to stack  
    _nestedFiles.Push(_input);  
      
    // This new stream will be popped and used right after, on DQUOTE.  
    _nestedFiles.Push(new AntlrInputStream(s));  

} -> skip;  
  
// Skipped because we don't want to hide DQUOTE's existance from parser  
DQUOTE: '"' { 

    // Injecting the newly generated Stream.  
    this._input = _nestedFiles.Pop();

    Mode(INCLexerGrammar.DefaultMode);

} -> skip;
```

**Parser Grammar:**

```
parser grammar INCParserGrammar;  
  
options { tokenVocab = INCLexerGrammar; }  
  
// Our Grammar contains only ANY tokens. Include directives  
// and other Tokens exists only for helping lexer to  
// inject the contents of other files inside the current  
// scanning process.  
  
compileUnit  
  :  ANY+ EOF  
  ;
```

**Execution Calls:**

```cs
// [...]

var myRootFile = new StreamReader("./root.txt");
var myAntlrInputStream = new AntlrInputStream(myRootFile);

var lexer = new INCLexerGrammar(myAntlrInputStream);
var tokens = new BufferedTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new INCParserGrammar(tokens);

parser.compileUnit();

// [...]
```